# Delete a directory under Cryptkeeper without access to its account

Tags: files, permissions

I have a computer with read-write permissions for one of it is directories. I lost the password that can help me to log in to that directory. How can I delete this folder.
I am using the following command to delete any directory but it is not working at that level?

```
rm -rf /path/to/dir
```

I am running Linux Fedora on my laptop. I used cryptkeeper to protect this folder by a password and to encrypt it and I can't access it now. I want to remove this folder.

Comment: Can you indicate how you login to a folder, you normally login to an account. If you can you login as root on that system, then you can delete any directory.

Comment: I am running linux fedora on my won laptop I used cryptkeeper to protect this folder by password and to encrypt it and I can't access it now. I want to remove this folder

Comment: Are you using the command with `sudo` ?

Comment: yes I am using the command sudo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cryptkeeper stores the files in a 'hidden' directory, one whose filename starts with a `.`. If you normally would have the files under `/path/to/` in a directory called `dir`, then you should do

```
 ls -a `/path/to/`
```

and see a directory   `.dir` there. That is the directory that contains the encrypted version of the files.

Confirm that that is so with ls -l `/path/to/.dir` (notice the `.`), you should see the names of the files you had stored, and then proceed to delete with `rm -rf /path/to/.dir/`.

Comment: I tried this but I got the message "access denied"

Comment: @MJA Then login as root, or use sudo to get rid of the directory and files. If you cannot do that list the output of `ls -la path_to_your_dir_with_dot_dirs` in your question.